# Guaranteeing you can recreate a build with git

Tags: git

I'm in a quandry using git with nightly builds.  If we clone the repo every day at 12:01am, build it and test it then how can we guarantee we get the same build every time?

The first method is to tag the build.  We'd pull the tag and build.  The problem is our system becomes littered with tags.  We could delete tags, but there's always a chance someone will need a deleted tag.

The second method is git checkout `git rev-list` by date/time.  The flaw is that change sets are time stamped at the time of commit - not when they're pushed.  So if someone does a commit (but no push) at 9pm on 7/30/13 and then a push the next day on 7/31/13.  Doing:

`` git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2013-07-31 0:01" master` ``

gets different results depending on whether or not the checkout was done before or after the push.

Am I misunderstanding something or is there a better way to do this in git?

Comment: Ummm... If you are doing "nightly builds", wouldn't the idea be to *not* "get the same build every time"? If you want the same build, then just build it once and keep it... Otherwise, take note of the commit you are on (`git rev-parse --verify HEAD`) and store that hash away somewhere, in case you ever need to replicate that particular build.

Comment: @twalberg: I think OP wants to be able to reproduce a particular nightly build exactly for test or debugging reasons.

Comment: @twalberg "store that hash away somewhere" is exactly that tags do. There is no reason to invent something else.

Comment: @kan I realize that, and I think OP did too, but didn't want to "clutter the tag space"...

Comment: @twalberg And it looks like a NIH syndrome...

Comment: @Scott "system becomes littered with tags" can you explain what that means? What particular problems is this causing for you?

Comment: @zespri A fatal flaw? :) http://www.hornlo.org/lohnet/wdjef/

Comment: @kan Good god! Thank you for sharing! I enjoyed it thoroughly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is no point to clone a repo everytime, it is too slow. Just do it once, then pull changes, use `git clear -xdf` to make a pristine wc before each build. Secondly, tags are cheap. If you run build everyday, it will create ~1000 tags in 3 years, each tag is less than 100 bytes, so you end up with 100kb per 3 years. Why do you care?

The repository which is used for builds could create tags locally and don't push it to main repository. It means if you need a tag, you could go to the repo directly and find a tag. If you look to a CI server (e.g. Jenkins) it tags each build automatically, and by default doesn't push tags back. Not sure why you are not using one already, you should consider it.

Comment: Good ideas-I appreciate the inputs!  For brevity, I didn't elaborate on details, but background is helpful.  My company converted from CVS a few weeks ago so we just joined the 21st century.  We're still a decade behind but we'll get there!  And only one guy deleted the remote. At least the doughnuts were tasty, but I digress.

I accepted to kan's answer because Bamboo is on the roadmap but I'm in the midst of converting to Stash/JIRA/Confluence.  Local tags make sense but I perversely like the idea of squirreling away commit hashes because its easy to explain to git noobs like ourselves.

Comment: @Scott tags/branches are mere human-friendly names for sha1 hashes, nothing fancy about them. Even easier - a tag or a branch is a regular file placed inside `.git/refs/` folder which just contains sha1, you could see it here and it may demist your understanding. Look inside `.git` folder, it has very simple and clear structure.